# Не правильная кодировка при ответе с сервера в Python 3

Tags: php, python, json, urllib

Здравствуйте. 
Пишу софтину на Python 3. Нужно сделать запрос к серверу, чтобы тот вернул обычный JSON. Работаю с кодировкой UTF-8.
Эта кодировка указана везде: в конфиге сервера, в заголовке PHP-скрипта, в Python-скрипте (`# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`), сами файлы скриптов тоже в UTF-8.
Но при попытке раскодировать пришедший ответ из UTF-8, появляется ошибка:

```
[Decode error - output not utf-8]
```

А если раскодировать ответ кодировкой cp1251, то всё прекрасно работает. Мне интересно, откуда взялась эта кодировка?

Код на питоне:

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from urllib.parse import urlencode
import json

req = Request("http://devcave.ru/json.php")
response = urlopen(req)
data = response.read().decode('cp1251')
data = json.loads(data)

print(response.headers.get_content_charset())
print(data)
```

Вывод кода на питоне:

```
utf-8
{'key': 'русский язык'}
```

PHP-код на сервере:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode(array('key' => 'русский язык'), JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Comment: Перепишите ответ отдельным сообщением и пометьте его решенным. Соблюдайте правила.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если на банку с солеными огурцами наклеить этикетку "Клубничное варенье", то к чаю предлагать содержимое все равно не стоит.

Так вот хидер - это только этикетка. Сама по себе она текст не перекодирует.
Сам текст в файле должен быть в utf-8 - тогда и раскодируется нормально.
Косвенно это можно проверить по содержимому JSON строки - без специального флага UTF символы будут закодированы в `\u0430` последовательности

Comment: Ага, это я понимаю, поэтому все возможные файлы сохранены в utf-8.
Если убрать флаг, то сервер отдаёт такой результат:
`{"key":"\u0440\u0443\u0441\u0441\u043a\u0438\u0439 \u044f\u0437\u044b\u043a"}`

Comment: @StanislavKuznetsov если пришедшая строка - не байтовая, а юникодная, и в ней тем не менее закодированы юникодные символы, вы можете воспользоваться функцией `codecs.unicode_escape_decode(s)` из стандартного модуля `codecs`

Answer (score 0):

**Решение:**
На самом деле при декодировании строки вместо cp1251 можно и нужно было использовать utf-8 - при этом всё проходит без ошибок, что означат, что все кодировки везде настроены правильно. Проблема была в функции print, которая отказывалась выводить раскодированную строку и становилась инициатором ошибки. Последствия перехода с Python 2 на 3. Спасибо всем, кто пытался помочь)